# InDesign CS5 Script: opening a document is unresponsive, and isn't throwing an error?

Tags: error-handling, execute, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I am using the method  `myFile.execute()`  to open an InDesign document programmatically (in this case, it is a blank document with styles applied to it).

---

The document is sometimes opened, and at other times it is ***not***... It seems as if the script does not have enough time to open the file before it is done.

---

This occurred to me because upon testing with  `alert(template.name)`  it *does* show the file name I'm looking for, and the script does ***not*** throw an error when applying  `File(template).execute()`  (the variable  `template`  is itself already a  `File`  object, but simply  `template.execute()`  is not working either).

---

Here is the relevant code:

```
function openStylesTemplate()
{
    var templateFolder = getScriptFolder(); // with the function below
    var fileArray = templateFolder.getFiles("*.indd"); // an array of all InDesign documents in this script's same folder

    try
    {
        var template = fileArray[0]; // the ONLY InDesign document in the folder
        File(template).execute(); // open the InDesign template document
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert("Error: " + e.message + "\n\n" +
                 "Make sure the InDesign styles document is in the same folder as this script,\n" +
                  "and that it is the ONLY InDesign document in this folder, and try again.\n\n" +
                 "This script is in this folder: " + templateFolder + ".");

        exit();
     }
} // end of function openStylesTemplate
```

So, could the script possibly not have enough time to load the document? If so, should I create a timer before this function is called? Or is there a better way to open an InDesign document programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening an indesign document isn't matter of `File.execute()` which simply opens a file from the os point of view without any reference to the file itself. You do open files by calling `app.open ( file );`.

Comment: Ah ok, so there are no errors, I am just using the wrong method! Thanks for clarifying the difference between these methods.